# Why can't I fetch data synchronously using HTTP GET in Angular5 when I don't want an asynchronous call

Tags: angular, http, asynchronous, observable

Say I am using an observable to watch an `HTTP` `GET` method in an Angular 5 application, and that I have an object, `fetchedData`, that stores data that is retrieved from this method.

If I don't know when the `GET` is going to complete, and I need to use its values in my next operation, what is the point of fetching the data asynchronously?

Is asynchronous retrieval useful if there is code to be executed that is not dependent on the data being fetched asynchronously (and, if so, does Angular identify the dependent-on-fetched-data code from the independent code)?

Consequently, is there a way to fetch data synchronously using HTTP requests in Angular 5?

Comment: The point is that Javascript is single-threaded and if you made a blocking call, the whole user interface would freeze. You really need to work with asynchronous requests.

Comment: I'm fetching data to display in a UI without which the user can't do anything. When I try to access the object after the async call, I get an error 'Cannot read property __ of undefined'. How do I know when it is safe to access the object and what should I do till it completes? By using the complete method of observables?

Comment: You can convert your observable to a promise and use aync/await pattern

Comment: Another option is to use a route resolver. It allows your component code to work with the data synchronously.

Answer (score 1):

`this.somePromiseReturningCall().then()` if you are using Promise object can work. But I would advise against it, s it blocks the whole webpage until you get the response.

But it is much better to create a boolean object, which blocks the affected user view.

For instance you have a

```
isPageReady = false;
```

variable.
then in the html:

```
<div [disabled]="!isPageReady"> .... </div>
```

(or you can hide it,or create overlay on it with "loading..." label, etc.)

then in your DB call:

```
   this.httpClient
      .get(<params>)
      .subscribe(response => {
       <process the response>
       this.isPageReady = true;
    });
  }
```